# Add checkbox setting to a multiple value field

Tags: entities

I have an image field with unlimited values. I want to add a checkbox to each image to use this image on the homepage. I would then check for that value in tpl file. How do I add a checkbox setting to this field?

Looks like a user did it in this post but didn't state how: [Add a configuration checkbox in field setting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41840/add-a-configuration-checkbox-in-field-setting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [field collections](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) to group fields together.. Field settings is used for field configuration...

According to your requirement you would like to choose for each field value associated value to track whether image should be displayed or not in home page.. Field collections does this and have integration with [views](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views)..